# Iterable gzip deflate/inflate in Java

Tags: java, gzip, nio

Is there a library for gzip-deflating in terms of ByteBuffers hidden in the Internet? Something which allows us to push raw data then pull deflated data? We have searched for it but found only libraries which deal with InputStreams and OutputStreams.

We are tasked with creating gzip filters for deflating a flow of ByteBuffers in a pipeline architecture. This is a pull architecture where the last element pulls data from earlier elements. Our gzip filter deals with a flow of ByteBuffers, there is no single Stream object available.

We have toyed with adapting the data flow as some kind of InputStream and then use GZipOutputStream to satisfy our requirements but the amount of adaptor code is annoying to say the least.

**Post-accept edit**: for the record, our architecture is similar to that of GStreamer and the likes.

Comment: I was vaguely under the impression that you have to have the entire input all at once to be able to gzip it properly -- that's probably why it expects an InputStream, whereas ByteBuffers are typically used for storing intermediate data, not for holding an entire file.

Comment: Not really gzip, but there's the [JZlib](http://www.jcraft.com/jzlib/) which is intended to provide (de-)coding in 'flexible' chunks, as opposed to Java's ZIP support functions. [Zlib is not gzip](http://www.zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq18), of course, but maybe you can still leverage it somehow.

Comment: @Hanno Java 7 includes the crucial Deflater.SYNC_FLUSH constant for transmitting blocks of compressed data efficiently.

Comment: @Hanno, we could implement gzip with the primitives in a zlib-like library, yes. If we find no pre-existing solution, we will probably contribute one to Github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Much credit to Mark Adler for suggesting this approach, which is much better than my original answer.

```
package stack;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;

public class BufferDeflate2 {
    /** The standard 10 byte GZIP header */
    private static final byte[] GZIP_HEADER = new byte[] { 0x1f, (byte) 0x8b,
            Deflater.DEFLATED, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    /** CRC-32 of uncompressed data. */
    private final CRC32 crc = new CRC32();

    /** Deflater to deflate data */
    private final Deflater deflater = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION,
            true);

    /** Output buffer building area */
    private final ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    /** Internal transfer space */
    private final byte[] transfer = new byte[1000];

    /** The flush mode to use at the end of each buffer */
    private final int flushMode;


    /**
     * New buffer deflater
     * 
     * @param syncFlush
     *            if true, all data in buffer can be immediately decompressed
     *            from output buffer
     */
    public BufferDeflate2(boolean syncFlush) {
        flushMode = syncFlush ? Deflater.SYNC_FLUSH : Deflater.NO_FLUSH;
        buffer.write(GZIP_HEADER, 0, GZIP_HEADER.length);
    }


    /**
     * Deflate the buffer
     * 
     * @param in
     *            the buffer to deflate
     * @return deflated representation of the buffer
     */
    public ByteBuffer deflate(ByteBuffer in) {
        // convert buffer to bytes
        byte[] inBytes;
        int off = in.position();
        int len = in.remaining();
        if( in.hasArray() ) {
            inBytes = in.array();
        } else {
            off = 0;
            inBytes = new byte[len];
            in.get(inBytes);
        }

        // update CRC and deflater
        crc.update(inBytes, off, len);
        deflater.setInput(inBytes, off, len);

        while( !deflater.needsInput() ) {
            int r = deflater.deflate(transfer, 0, transfer.length, flushMode);
            buffer.write(transfer, 0, r);
        }

        byte[] outBytes = buffer.toByteArray();
        buffer.reset();
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(outBytes);
    }


    /**
     * Write the final buffer. This writes any remaining compressed data and the GZIP trailer.
     * @return the final buffer
     */
    public ByteBuffer doFinal() {
        // finish deflating
        deflater.finish();

        // write all remaining data
        int r;
        do {
            r = deflater.deflate(transfer, 0, transfer.length,
                    Deflater.FULL_FLUSH);
            buffer.write(transfer, 0, r);
        } while( r == transfer.length );

        // write GZIP trailer
        writeInt((int) crc.getValue());
        writeInt((int) deflater.getBytesRead());

        // reset deflater
        deflater.reset();

        // final output
        byte[] outBytes = buffer.toByteArray();
        buffer.reset();
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(outBytes);
    }


    /**
     * Write a 32 bit value in little-endian order
     * 
     * @param v
     *            the value to write
     */
    private void writeInt(int v) {
        System.out.println("v="+v);
        buffer.write(v & 0xff);
        buffer.write((v >> 8) & 0xff);
        buffer.write((v >> 16) & 0xff);
        buffer.write((v >> 24) & 0xff);
    }


    /**
     * For testing. Pass in the name of a file to GZIP compress
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File inFile = new File(args[0]);
        File outFile = new File(args[0]+".test.gz");
        FileChannel inChan = (new FileInputStream(inFile)).getChannel();
        FileChannel outChan = (new FileOutputStream(outFile)).getChannel();

        BufferDeflate2 def = new BufferDeflate2(false);

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(500);
        while( true ) {
            buf.clear();
            int r = inChan.read(buf);
            if( r==-1 ) break;
            buf.flip();
            ByteBuffer compBuf = def.deflate(buf);
            outChan.write(compBuf);
        }

        ByteBuffer compBuf = def.doFinal();
        outChan.write(compBuf);

        inChan.close();
        outChan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like our preferred solution.

Comment: Hmm. It seems like you have a bug here; `needsInput()` is checked if you need to add more impot, whereas `finished()` is checked if there is more output, so your use of `needsInput()` should be changed to `finished()`.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand the "hidden in the internet" part, but [zlib](http://zlib.net/) does in-memory gzip format compression and decompression.  The [`java.util.zip` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) provides some access to zlib, though it is limited.  Due to the interface limitations, you cannot request that zlib produce and consume gzip streams directly.  You can however use the `nowrap` option to produce and consume raw deflate data.  Then it's easy to roll your own gzip header and trailer, using the `CRC32` class in `java.util.zip`.  You can prepend a fixed 10-byte header, append the four-byte CRC and then the four-byte uncompressed length (modulo 2<sup>32</sup>), both in little-endian order, and you're good to go.

Comment: The "hidden in the internet" part refers to "we have searched for it" and the fact we could not find anything which does not require Stream objects to be available.

Comment: Wow. An answer by the author of JZLib. :-D

Comment: I am one of the two authors of zlib.  JZlib is a translation / adaptation of zlib to Java done by Atsuhiko Yamanaka.

Comment: Ah, ok, I totally misread that -- I thought that somehow the ByteBuffers were hidden in the internet, since it said "ByteBuffers hidden in the Internet".

Comment: hm. Re-reading my question, your confusion makes sense. My fault.

Answer (score 1):

Processing ByteBuffers is not hard. See my sample code below. You need to know how the buffers are created. The options are:

1. Each buffer is compressed independently. This is so simple to handle I assume this is not the case. You would just transform the buffer into a byte array and wrap it in an ByteArrayInputStream within a GZIPInputStream.
2. Each buffer was ended with a SYNC_FLUSH by the writer, and thus comprises an entire block of data within a stream. All the data written by the writer to the buffer can be read immediately by the reader.
3. Each buffer is just part of a GZIP stream. There is no guarantee the reader can read anything from the buffer.

Data generated by GZIP must be processed in order. The ByteBuffers will have to be processed in the same order they are generated.

Sample code:

```
package stack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.Pipe;
import java.nio.channels.SelectableChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;

public class BufferDeflate {

    static AtomicInteger idSrc = new AtomicInteger(1);

    /** Queue for transferring buffers */
    final BlockingQueue<ByteBuffer> buffers = new LinkedBlockingQueue<ByteBuffer>();

    /** The entry point for deflated buffers */
    final Pipe.SinkChannel bufSink;

    /** The source for the inflater */
    final Pipe.SourceChannel infSource;

    /** The destination for the inflater */
    final Pipe.SinkChannel infSink;

    /** The source for the outside world */
    public final SelectableChannel source;



    class Relayer extends Thread {
        public Relayer(int id) {
            super("BufferRelayer" + id);
        }


        public void run() {
            try {
                while( true ) {
                    ByteBuffer buf = buffers.take();
                    if( buf != null ) {
                        bufSink.write(buf);
                    } else {
                        bufSink.close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    class Inflater extends Thread {
        public Inflater(int id) {
            super("BufferInflater" + id);
        }


        public void run() {
            try {
                InputStream in = Channels.newInputStream(infSource);
                GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                OutputStream out = Channels.newOutputStream(infSink);

                int ch;
                while( (ch = gzip.read()) != -1 ) {
                    out.write(ch);
                }
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * New buffer inflater
     */
    public BufferDeflate() throws IOException {
        Pipe pipe = Pipe.open();
        bufSink = pipe.sink();
        infSource = pipe.source();

        pipe = Pipe.open();
        infSink = pipe.sink();
        source = pipe.source().configureBlocking(false);

        int id = idSrc.incrementAndGet();

        Thread thread = new Relayer(id);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        thread = new Inflater(id);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }


    /**
     * Add the buffer to the stream. A null buffer closes the stream
     * 
     * @param buf
     *            the buffer to add
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void add(ByteBuffer buf) throws IOException {
        buffers.offer(buf);
    }
}
```

Simply pass the buffers to the `add` method and read from the public `source` channel. The amount of data that can be read from GZIP after processing a given number of bytes is impossible to predict. I have therefore made the `source` channel non-blocking so you can safely read from it in the same thread that you add the byte buffers.

Comment: Your solution seems correct but requires too many resources.
That is what we discovered when trying to adapt the gzip stream classes in java.util.zip.
Our experience with similar components (e.g. encryption filters) tells us this must be simpler and cheaper.

Comment: Too many resources for what? The above is about as simple as you can get whilst handling I/O blocking. If you want cheap, go with Mark Adler's answer. He is a huge expert on working with zip formats in Java.

Comment: Queues and pipes and threads seem excessive for this problem.

Comment: As I already implied, if you want simple go with Mark Adler's answer :)