# nio HTTP decompression in Java

Tags: java, nio, compression

Is there any Java library that does nio decompression of GZIP (and possibly other formats) out there? 
I'm trying to analyze compressed HTTP content and need it to be non-blocking.
I found GZipInputStream but it expects InputStream which is blocking.
Any ideas?

I also found [Iterable gzip deflate/inflate in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387215/iterable-gzip-deflate-inflate-in-java)
talking about compression (deflate) but couldn't find a decompression equivalent.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using Netty's [ZLibWrapper](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/compression/ZlibWrapper.html)?